# Attempting to set HTML element object by using getElementsByID returns nothing; ID exists in HTML page

Tags: excel, vba, mshtml, serverxmlhttp

I'm attempting to scrape some tracking data from UPS' website and I'm able to get this to work using MSInternet Controls and opening an instance of IE, but when I attempt to do the same using an XML request to save time I can't seem to assign the element I need so I can extract the innerText from it.

The issue seems to be where I set the HTMLTrackStatus using the getelementsbyid method. When I place a stop in the code right before printing to the immediate window, I check the contents of HTMLTrackStatus and it shows as "Nothing"

When I run the code the error window tells me that object or with variable not set. This makes sense because it's not being set, but I cannot figure out why it's not returning my HTML element using that ID (which does exist).

I am able to get the tracking status from this HTML element using a MS internet controls and opening IE using VBA, but this is slow.

Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument 
Dim HTMLTrackStatus As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

XMLPage.Open "GET", "https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&tracknum=1Z9E700W0317182871&requester=WT/trackdetails", False 
XMLPage.send 'send the request

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

Set HTMLTrackStatus = HTMLDoc.getElementById("stApp_txtPackageStatus")

Debug.Print HTMLTrackStatus.innerText

I place my stop at the debug line, and when I check the contents of HTMLTrackStatus it returns "nothing". why is this not returning the element I need?

Comment: You should try HTMLTrackStatus.outerText

Comment: Content is loaded dynamically from API call. See linked duplicate.

Comment: @EddiGordo thanks Eddi, but the I think the problem starts before i'm even trying to print the inner text of the element.

Comment: @QHarr looked at the link you provided and it doesn't seem to answer my question. I see he's trying to procure tracking, but I'm not using JSON (not sure what that is, sorry I'm new to all of this). I would like know to exactly why my call to getelementbyid is not returning anything so I can understand how to resolve it. is there perhaps another thread that speaks more to this specific issue? I tried searching but couldn't find anything.

Comment: You want to use xhr to get the data. The data is provided dynamically from an xhr to the API shown in that answer. With standard xhr to your original url javascript doesn't run and so that content is not present (there is no additional call to the API).  The data from the API  is returned in json format.  You then need to parse the json for any info that you want.  So you either call that API or use a browser.  The content of that json tells you the tracking status i.e. if delivered.

Comment: For info about json see: https://www.json.org/ and [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=json+user%3A9912714+is%3Aanswer)

Comment: okay I guess I need to learn about json. thanks!